# jQuery storyboard next previous

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to create the storyboard idea that oDesk uses on http://www.odesk.com/w/odesk_story

I like the way the html is laid out but I can't seem to find the javascript that controls it.

If I were to recreate that functionality exactly, what would be the best plugin to use.

Or for that matter is it hard to write it myself?

In summary.

There would be 5 story blocks with the first one shown and the others hidden. As you click next it hides the first and shows the next one.

Lets assume we want a jquery code that can handle different amounts of slides.

Bit rusty on my jQuery, any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. Would do me no harm to try write my own code.

UPDATE:

In the end, I actually got it working without any javascript. I just used anchor text and overflow:hidden amount a few other css attributes to make it work.  The only thing is it doesn't have a nice slide effect. If I want to add a transition to an anchor link what is the best way to do that?

UPDATE 2:

For anyone that is interested you can view the end product here; 
http://www.fishpond.ie/howitworks.html

Comment: If you want to see their code, go to the page, enable all panels in firebug, reload the page, and they'll be available in the scripts tab of firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created something very similar using [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an advertising banner similar to what you are describing recently using [easySlider](http://cssglobe.com/post/3783/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider). Its pretty nice out of the box and I managed to modify the code a bit to enable both next/previous as well as the numeric slide select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there no problem to do it using only with jQuery and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

You can run and slide effect http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/ and toggle the div to display:none